# C# WPF removes Canvas Width & Height as soon as re-sizing happens

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Why does  the XAML-Editor removes `Width` & `Height` property and replaces them with the `Margin` property as soon as I resize my elements to desired size? The `Height`, `Width`, `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties are always zero in my code because of that. It just seems so unreasonable to me to do that.

I also tried this:

```
sideCanvas.Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    Drawer = new Drawer(sideCanvas, mainCanvas);
    CreateRectangles();
    Drawer.Rectangles = rectangles;
    rectangles.ForEach(rect => rect.ActivateEvents());
};
```

Doesn't work (`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` is 0). Is it so unusual to access width and height of an element that Microsoft just sets them to 0?

Comment: Why are you using the designer? You shoud learn XAML.

Comment: Because it is easier to design the UI with visuals and drag & drop. Creating UIs with XML-like Code is from the 90s.